# How do I create a List by applying an operation to all elements of a scala Map?

Tags: scala

I have a scala map `myMap` and I want to create a list `MyList` of pairs as follows:

> For each (k,v) in myMap, MyList should have the Tuple (v.someMember, k) as an element

The result of using `map` and `for` comprehension is a new map. Is there a better way to do this than to start with an empty list and add the elements as I loop through the (key, value) pairs in map

```
var myList = List.empty[(Double, String)]
myMap foreach { case(k,v) => myList ::= (v.someMember, k) }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `toList` and then `map`.

For example:

```
scala> Map("a" -> 1, "b" -> 2).toList.map { case (k, v) => (k.size, v) }
res12: List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,1), (1,2))
```

Or, if you want to be more memory efficient and do not allocate intermediate list, you can build list while `map`ing with `breakOut`

```
import scala.collection.breakOut

scala> val l: List[(Int, Int)] = Map("a" -> 1, "b" -> 2).map({ case (k, v) => (k.size, v) })(breakOut)
l: List[(Int, Int)] = List((1,1), (1,2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider also this for comprehension syntax (here semantically equivalent to `map` as already suggested); for instance for

```
val myMap = Map (1.1 -> "abc" , 2.2 -> "xyz")

for ( (k,v) <- myMap.toList ) yield v(2) -> k
```

Following the question statement,

```
for ( (k,v) <- myMap.toList ) yield v.someMember -> k
```